# how to display decoded base64 pdf file from encoded base64 string in database in python?

Tags: python, pdf

bytes = b64decode(encoded_string, validate=True) if bytes[0:4] != b'%PDF': raise ValueError('Missing the PDF file signature') f = open('file.pdf', 'wb') f.write(bytes) f.close() want to display "file.pdf"

f = open('file.pdf', 'rb') dat = f.read() return dat # get byte wrong format pdf file

Comment: Can you fix the code? Get the lines and indents right then select and make it a code block. The help text tells you how.

Comment: You write file.pdf....can that file be opened by a pdf reader? You've decoded some base64 but we have no way of knowing what's inside.

Comment: I voted to close your question. The reason is that in its current form, there is no way for anybody here to help you. Provide more detail, format your question properly using the editing tools and I'm sure you'll have a much better chance to find an answer.